# RegEx match but ignore in the result

Tags: regex

Consider the following string

```
'#PI + #C + 1.2'
```

i am trying to get each word after the hash but also ignore the hash in the result

i use

```
#(\S+)
```

which is fine but i am not sure how to make sure the hash is there but ignore it in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer works, here is how I would go about it:

```
#([^\s]+)\s*
```

**Which reads like**: Match a "#", then capture all non-space chars into the first capture group (there has to be at-least one non-space char). After that, match an arbitrary number of spaces.

The entire reg-ex would not "match" or evaluate to true, unless the "#" is found before a bunch of non-whitespace chars.

Obviously, if you are guaranteed of the form `#XXX + #YYY + CCC`, you can construct a much more targeted reg-ex to pick the appropriate values into the correct capture groups.

**Edit:**
Just noticed that you said "the # shows up in the result", the "result" of what? Typically the regex match object will return the entire matched string, if you are looking to get the contents of `(...)` - you will have to access the appropriate capture group of the matched regex. And that is very language dependent. In python you can do:

```
re_SOMETHING = re.compile("#([^\s]+)\s*", ...)
match = re_SOMETHING.match("#PI + #C + 1.2")
if match:
    pi = match.group(1)
    # pi === "PI"
```

Comment: Edited my answer, the "/"s are there by force of habit :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you mean by ignoring the # in the result. Your regex is doing just that. It matches the # to make sure it's there and then only captures the stuff after it. If you don't want the # to match at all you have to use zero-width assertions or look arounds:

```
(?<=#)(\S+)
```

Comment: what i need is to make sure the # is there, but only take the word after it, i use substring in the language i am using to remove the # from the result, but i was wondering if there is a way to do it directly from RegEx

Comment: @FPGA I see. The above regex would not have the # in the matches.

Comment: @FPGA Seems like regepal doesn't support lookbehinds. Try http://regexhero.net/tester